# assigning a json dictionary key value to a variable

Tags: python, json

I have a json with the following structure.

```
{
    "source": {
        "excelsheetname": {
            "convert_to_csv": "True",
            "tgt_folder": "archieve/datetime=",
            "brand": "chicken",
            "sheets": {
                "sheet1":{
                    "headers": 5,
                    "columns": 1
                },
                "sheet2": {
                    "headers": 3,
                    "columns": 2
                },
                "sheet3": {
                    "headers": 5,
                    "columns": 3
                },
                "sheet4": {
                    "headers": 3,
                    "columns": 2
                }
            }
        }
```

What I am trying to do is create a for loop assign the sheet headers and columns to a variable.

This is what my code looks like:

```
for i in config['source']['excelsheetname']['sheets'][i]:
    if i == "headers":
        value = i['headers']
```

But this code doesnt work, as I keep getting the `"TypeError: string indices must be integers"`

Comment: you are adding a `[i]` in your for loop initiation, it should be removed and your code will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to parse the JSON into a Python dictionary:

```py
import json
config_str = """
{
    "source": {
        "excelsheetname": {
            "convert_to_csv": "True",
            "tgt_folder": "archieve/datetime=",
            "brand": "chicken",
            "sheets": {
                "sheet1":{
                    "headers": 5,
                    "columns": 1
                },
                "sheet2": {
                    "headers": 3,
                    "columns": 2
                },
                "sheet3": {
                    "headers": 5,
                    "columns": 3
                },
                "sheet4": {
                    "headers": 3,
                    "columns": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
"""
config = json.loads(config_str)
```

From your question, I understood that you want to get a list of the headers and a list of the columns. When you iterate over a dictionary in Python, you have two values: the key and the value. We can use the `values()` method to iterate only over the values. Your code iterates over an expression that includes the loop variable, which doesn't make sense, as the variable doesn't exist until then. You could use a simple for loop to get what you want:

```py
for sheetname, sheet in config["source"]["excelsheetname"]["sheets"].items():
    headers = sheet["headers"]
    columns = sheet["columns"]
    # Processing
    print(headers + columns, sheetname) # Just an example of processing
```

Comment: I think you meant `for _, sheet in config["source"]["excelsheetname"]["sheets"].items():` (otherwise you get  ValueError  too many values to unpack (expected 2). Or since the key is unused `for sheet in config["source"]["excelsheetname"]["sheets"].values():`

Comment: Also, your list comprehensions are incorrect i.e. give errors.

Comment: @DarrylG Thanks, didn't notice that at first. It should work now.

Comment: This works but not exactly what I want. My code example is just a piece of an even bigger function. The idea is to extract the header and column (first iteration) values apply some processing and then extract (second iteration) it again and do some processes.

Comment: @MurtazaMohsin I've edited to include processing by what I understood from your comment. If this isn't what you want, could you elaborate a bit more on what you do?

Comment: okay this works but could I also then extract the sheetname under the loop? For example sheet1, sheet2. The main idea of the function is to convert an excel file into a csv. The excel file has multiple sheets that start from either row & column 4,5 and etc. The function reads the excel file using pandas, uses the assigned row and column numbers to process them into csv's.

Comment: @MurtazaMohsin Hopefully it's good now. I just used the `items()` method of a dictionary instead of `values` to get a 2-tuple of `(key, value)` where the key in this case is the name of the sheet and the value is the dictionary containing sheet info.

Answer (score -1):

Not quiet sure if i get your question right but this will deliever the integer at key `"headers"` and `"columns"` for every `sheet` in `sheets`

```
    for i in config['source']['excelsheetname']['sheets'].keys():
        
        if "header" in config['source']['excelsheetname']['sheets'][i].keys():
            header_value= config['source']['excelsheetname']['sheets'][i]["headers"]
            print(header_value) # store it or do whatever you want
        if "columns" in config['source']['excelsheetname']['sheets']
            column_value = config['source']['excelsheetname']['sheets'][i]["columns"]
            print(column_value ) # store it or do whatever you want
```

Comment: So essentially there are more things I need to do after the loop but what I am trying to do is just loop through the json get the specific header and column value.